# Need help locating the reason for "Segmentation fault" in this piece of C++ code

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault

I have the following code

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    int NoOfArr;
    std::cin >> NoOfArr;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> VecOfVecs;
    for(int i = 0; i <= NoOfArr; ++i) {
        int x;
        // Add all elements
        std::vector<int> temp;

        std::string str;
        std::getline(std::cin, str);
        std::istringstream sstr(str);
        while(sstr >> x) {
            temp.push_back(x);
        }
        std::cout << "reached2" << std::endl;
        temp.erase(temp.begin());
        VecOfVecs.push_back(temp);
    }
return 0;
}
```

which is supposed to take an input such as

```
2
3 1 5 4
5 1 2 3 4 5
```

The idea is that I want to make a vector of vectors (kind of like a nested list in Python) where the first element in this vector of vectors is the vector {1,5,4} and the second is {1,2,3,4,5}. I don't care about the first digits of the 2nd and 3rd line of the input for now, so I drop them. However, something seems to be going wrong with reading the input, because the `while` loop is skipped and the code returns a "Segmentation fault". I'm quite new to the language so I've been unsuccessful in finding what causes this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `NoOfQ` value?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel It actually plays no role here but is part of the code that this piece came out of. I will remove it

Comment: @J.Schultke Could you elaborate? As I said I'm not very experienced so I still cannot deduce where things go wrong based off your comment.

Comment: Your `for` loop condition is also wrong, it should be `i < NoOfArr` to loop `NoOfArr` times (twice in your example).

Comment: @Blastfurnace You're right, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `std::cin.ignore ();` after `std::cin >> NoOfArr;`.

`std::cin >> NoOfArr;` does not remove the end-of-line character from the input stream, which means that the next call to `getline` returns an empty string.  In consequence, vector `temp` is empty and so `temp.begin()` passes an invalid iterator to `temp.erase()`.

The code should test for `temp` being empty anyway, since it might be, depending on the input supplied to the program.

Comment: Interesting, makes sense. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2):

> I don't care about the first digits of the 2nd and 3rd line of the input for now, so I drop them.

Well, they are there for a purpose after all.

In fact, if you used them and read the stream directly into arrays, rather than first reading a string, you would probably escape this error.

Right now what happens is, you first consume the number of test data, from line 1, and then with `getline()` you still read line 1 (its EOL wasn't consumed on reading `NoOfArr`). The line comes empty, consequently no numbers are read from it, i.e. your `while` loop is 'skipped', and then you try to erase the begin of an empty array...

Comment: @bipll Thanks for the answer. I will look into reading it directly into arrays. Is there a way to consume the EOL on reading line 1 like you mentioned?

Comment: @CharlieShuffler either use `ignore` or simply an extra read with `getline`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::cin.ignore()` before calling the `std::getline(std::cin,str)`.

You press enter after typing `NoOfArr`and getline reads it as a line(so it considers first line of input in the for loop to be empty line) . It pushes nothing into vector in the first iteration but Then it tries to erase the `temp.begin()`. This is giving you segmentation fault.

Using `std::cin.ignore()` will skip `std::getline(std::cin,str)` from reading the enter key that you press after entering the first input.
This will probably solve your error. I hope this helps.

Comment: That was indeed the issue. I already accepted an answer, but thanks a lot anyway!